# Set background-color for div when using ng-repeat

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Hi I've got follow code:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.boxList = [{
    color: 'red'
  }, {
    color: '#F8F8F8'
  }, {
    color: 'rgb(50, 77, 32)'
  }];
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 15px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div ng-repeat="box in boxList" class="box" ng-style="{'background-color': box.color}"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to loop the `boxList` with `ng-repeat` and set the `background-color` (text, hex or rgb) for my div box. So there should be three boxes with three different colors. I tried it with `ng-style` (saw some examples in stackoverflow) but it doesn't work. Whats wrong, any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT: SOLUTION** -> `ng-style="{'background-color': box.color}`

`background-color` has to be within ' '.

Comment: Hi! Could you post the result, as an answer to your own question? I understand it might not be unlocked yet, but just as a reminder for later

Comment: Hi @HopefulLlama I just marked a answer as correct, which is simply the same like mine, so it's done. :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.boxList = [{
    color: 'red'
  }, {
    color: '#F8F8F8'
  }, {
    color: 'rgb(50, 77, 32)'
  }];
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 15px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div ng-repeat="box in boxList" class="box" ng-style="{'background-color':'{{box.color}}'}"></div>
</div>
```

you're syntax was off, you missed some quotes and should have used interpolation (`{{variable}}`) in order to render the value.

this is the only thing I changed: `ng-style="{'background-color':'{{box.color}}'}"` so you can see the difference. Good luck ;)

Comment: Works, thanks. I also put my own soluton as edit in the question

Comment: yes, I was in the snippet editor and didn't realised until after I posted the answer, thanks for accepting it :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
      <div ng-repeat="box in boxList" class="box" style="background : {{box.color}}">
</div>
```

Think this should do it

Comment: you can also use ng-style="{background : box.color}"
either way is fine though